# Which people/groups/departments are working on soil bioacoustics?

Tags: insect, monitoring, biotremology, invertebrates

I am a new PhD student at the University of Liverpool working on developing bioacoustic monitoring of belowground invertebrates in savanna habitats. It would be great to know if there are any other people/groups/departments working on something similar!

Comment: @Noil, reads now much better.

Answer (score 3):

Based on this CarlyBatist's [answer](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/a/106/73) from another SE thread, earthworm bioacoustics is studied by, e.g.:

- a team composed of [INRAE](https://www6.val-de-loire.inrae.fr/ur-sols_eng/) and the [Institute of Biogeochemistry and Pollutant Dynamics](https://ibp.ethz.ch/) (this [paper](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41598-018-28582-9))
- a team composed of [Stanford University](https://epsci.stanford.edu/), [Umeå University](https://www.umu.se/en/department-of-ecology-and-environmental-science/) and [University of Minnesota](https://swac.umn.edu/) (this [paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.scitotenv.2022.155976)).

as well as in an [art-science-oriented work](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/335826299_Sounding_Soil_An_Acoustic_Ecological_Artistic_Investigation_of_Soil_Life) by a team composed of [Zurich University of the Arts](https://www.zhdk.ch/en/zurich-university-of-the-arts-1), [Swiss Federal Institute](https://www.wsl.ch/en/about-wsl/organisation/research-units/forest-health-and-biotic-interactions/forest-entomology/), and [Agroscope](https://www.agroscope.admin.ch/agroscope/en/home/topics/environment-resources/soil-bodies-water-nutrients/nabo.html).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, and edits to my original post - both are very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Relating to soil bioacoustics and the Zurich connection, my colleague Marcus Maeder teaches, publishes, and mount sound art installation based this research: https://marcusmaeder.ch/research-teaching/

My best,
Eric

Comment: Hi Eric, 

Yes I have read a few of his papers, I may get in touch soon to ask a few questions.

Thank you so much for your reply,
Jonny

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you look to the work of Dr Carlos Abrahams at Baker Consultants and their collaborators at Warwick University.

See following links:

- https://bakerconsultants.co.uk/news/defra-grants-baker-consultants-major-ecoacoustics-research-grant/
- https://bakerconsultants.co.uk/news/the-sounds-of-soil-make-the-airwaves-on-bbc-radio-4-today/

Regards,
Seán

Comment: Hi Seán, thank you for your help and sending me the links, I have been in contact with Carlos :)